# Jquery to change HTML <p> text color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I just started trying to learn JQuery. I wanted to make a

change color on anchor click, but this code isn't working and I can't figure out why. I know this is very basic but it is the first step to me learning JQuery.

main.js :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#test').click(function () {
         $("p").css("color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

    <a id="test" href="#">
        <span>test</span>
    </a>


    <p>
        Hello
    </p>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you imported the script jQuery in you HTML?

Comment: Working as intended on Chrome

Comment: I used the line <script src="main.js"></script> to call it

Comment: It works in your example, even though your `<script>` tag is outside of `<html>`. `<script src='yourSrc.ext'></script>` tags should be in your `<head>`, really. Well, it did work. I think someone edited your code.

Comment: Is the file loading correctly? . Add an alert in the file or check  view source and click on the link or inspect element -> network to be sure the  js file is loading

Comment: It does not work for me. I press the anchor and nothing happens.

Comment: Put all of your `<script>` tags in your `<head>` and use `$(function(){ /* execute your code here */ });`. If you're just learning, I would learn good old vanilla JavaScript... it now has `.querySelectorAll` and `.querySelector`... and CSS 3 supports transitions with easing. So no need for jQuery.

Comment: When I inspect the page and go to the main.js file, it says jQuery undefined.

Comment: You need the jQuery `<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>` in your `<head><!-- in here --></head>` above your `<body>` and below your opening `<html>` tags.

Comment: it is working https://jsfiddle.net/7jzkvuhq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import jQuery library.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp